# add marginefigure in Recipe book

Tags: lyx, books, arabic

i used "Recipe book" class in lyx 2.1 , i want to add marginfigure from menu (gui) without tex code? (like tufte book).

regards

Comment: -1. The question is not clear, and it is cross-posted from `lyx-users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks,i got this code:

```
\begin{marginfigure} 
\centering 
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image name here}} 
\caption{text her} 
\end{marginfigure}
```

Comment: If you downvote, please also put a reason why